# On Mouse over on the high chart data the tool tip value should be displayed next to legend label

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, legend

```
I am using high chart in my project. Currently when user mouse over on the data points the tool tip will be displayed top to the data points. Some times the data are big and the tool tip will look very big, hence user wants to display the tool tip value next to the legend title during mouse over of the data points.
```

Example Legends should look like below:
 Female % 23        Male %  22
Here 23 and 22 are the data points value which should be printed next to legend label when we mouse over on the data points.
The 23 and 22 value should be changed as per the mouse over on the data points.

```
enter code here    
 primaryChart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                // my code

            },
            yAxis: [{
                // my code
            }],
            xAxis: {
               // my code
            },
            plotOptions: {
 // my code

            },

            tooltip: {
                //enabled: false,
                followPointer: false,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    //debugger;
                    var precision;
                    var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e %Y, %H:%M:%S', new Date(this.x)) + '</b>';
                    $.each(this.points, function () {
                        precision = GetTooltipData(this.series.options.paramID);
                        s += '<br/ ><span style="color:' + this.series.options.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span> : ' + parseFloat(this.y.toFixed(precision)) + ' ' + this.series.yAxis.axisTitle.textStr;
                        // s += "<div class='comment_filter'><a class='comments_buble' href='#' data-series='" + this.point.index + "'>Comment</a></div>";

                    });
                    return s;
                },
                shared: true
            },
            series: chartData,
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4,
                inputEnabled: false,
                buttonTheme: {
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                },
                labelStyle: {
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'left',
                borderColor: '#909090',
                verticalAlign: 'top'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            }     


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `positioner` function for tooltip to place it next to a legend:

```
tooltip: {
    positioner: function() {
        var legend = this.chart.legend,
            x = legend.group.translateX + legend.legendWidth,
            y = legend.group.translateY;

        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
    },
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3rsp4bdy/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

tooltip: {

```
            followPointer: true,
           useHTML: true,
          split: false,
          formatter: function () {
          var s = '<span>' + this.series.name +'</span>';             
          this.series.legendItem.element.innerHTML = s;
           return false;               
          },             
          shared: true,            
        },
```